# Magento Payment Methods Access Denied when Saving Configuration as non admin user

Tags: php, xml, magento, paypal

I think that the core Mage_Paypal module has an error regarding the ACL code in adminhtml.xml.

In app/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php at line 170 the path 'paypal/general/merchant_country' seems to be not unallowed:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($configPath)) {
                        Mage::throwException('Access denied.');
                    }
```

adminhtml.xml file is like that:

```
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <paypal>
                                    <title>PayPal Section</title>
                                </paypal>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
           </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

In system.xml I couldn't find any paypal section where you could save config values, only a field 'payment/account/merchant_country' that has a config_path tag with value 'paypal/general/merchant_country'.

Comment: did you find a solution fo this? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Mage_Paypal, this is Mage_Adminhtml. The problem is the check of the `config_path`.

A solution, I'm not 100% sure, in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data`, replace line 175:

`if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($configPath)) {`

by:

`if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/config/'.substr($configPath, 0, strpos($configPath, '/')))) {`

(tested with Magento 1.9.4.3)

Comment: Today I don't understand me. This must be fixed in OpenMage! https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/626